# Obtain facebook token access from authorization

Tags: facebook, facebook-authorization

I have a Facebook Account (Lets call him Admin), a Page, and an Application...
I have problems to obtain extended token for a Server Script to post in Page's Wall. In a lot of tutorials, they recommends to call this URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[APP_ID]&scope=manage_pages,publish_stream&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

I login with the Facebook account, apply the permissions, but instead of give me the code/token, I got a page with this:

Success
ADVERTENCIA DE SEGURIDAD: trata la dirección URL como si fuera tu contraseña y no la compartas con nadie.

With font red...
I've tried with 3 browsers, but same results.
What I'm doing wrong? Do you know a good (and updated) tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong flow and/or not handling the current authentication flow.

That flow is for desktop applications and you must parse the access token that is returned in the url thus the message,

> SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

Because the access token is given in the open.

See this page for mor information https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/